# Android Java Regex for email domain

Tags: regex

Hi I want to use a regex to check if an email is a gmail.com email address

I currently have this

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[gmail.com]
```

Which works until it gets the the g, shown in that image

[image]

If anyone can help that would be great

Comment: Remove `[` and `]` from around `gmail.com` and escape the `.` - `^[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@gmail\.com`. Add a `$` at the end if you are not using `matches()` and need to disallow anything after `gmail.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@gmail\.com$
```

Your mistake was the [] around the domain. With the brackets you define a group of characters that may occur, but you want the specific domain gmail.com. Thats why you should escape the . and add a $ for end of string. Otherwise this could also be a hit gmail-com.tld

Comment: Thank you for helping and explaining it!

Comment: @StewartWilliamFlack if all your questions are answered, pls accept this as answer

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets would only match a single character inside the set. You can use the modified regex where \S would match anything but a space.

```
\S+@gmail\.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Format should be in the following way;

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@gmail.com
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how it works, rather than just giving the answer